# How to delay syn ack

Tags: linux, tcp

Is there any way to delay the  `Syn-ACK` when the `SYN` is send by the client to the server and server has reply with `SYN-ACK`, in the three-way handshake protocol, is there any specific tuning required in sysctl.cnf file or whether it can be done by `iptables`  settings ?

Comment: Why would you want to delay it?  It sounds like you may be off track.  (No offense intended here)

Comment: Trying to figure our the network slowness Issue, when the SYN-ACK is delayed by the server